# What is this US Navy airplane seen at Westover AFB?

Tags: aircraft-identification, trainer, us-navy

[image: US Navy airplane at Westover AFB in 1987 or 1990?]

This Navy aircraft was at Westover AFB in either 1987 or 1990. Type unknown.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think it should be the [T-28C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_T-28_Trojan)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! I will update my website and my scrapbook!

Comment: And the helicopter is an AS350 Écureuil.

Comment: @PeterKämpf interesting... that means "squirrel" in French. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The full name is a North American T 28 Trojan.

Comment: This is already explained in the link in the previous answer. Feel free to edit the info into the existing answer, or post a comment (now that you have more rep) rather than posting another answer that doesn't add much.